# Determining section identifier for NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

I am attempting to create an `NSCollectionView` with a dynamic number of sections using `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout`.

The collection view is used for displaying search results and the number of sections depends on the type and number of results found. Each section displays its content type using a different layout.

The data source is declared as `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, SearchResult>` where `SearchResult` is a class implementing `Hashable` using `UUID()`. Sections with zero results are not empty, rather they don't exist in the collection view.

One of the difficulties I'm having is determining the section identifier corresponding to `sectionIndex` in the layout's `sectionProvider`:

```swift
private func createLayout() -> NSCollectionViewLayout {
    let sectionProvider = { (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection in
        // How can the section identifier corresponding to `sectionIndex` be determined?

        // Create a `NSCollectionLayoutSection` appropriate for the section type
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(/* ... */)
        return section
    }
    return NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: sectionProvider)
}
```

Since the collection view has a variable number of sections depending on search results, the type of items displayed section `0` may change.

See https://github.com/sbooth/DiffableTest for an example project.

Comment: Ask the data source for a snapshot and look at the list of section identifiers? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot/3182919-sectionidentifiers

Comment: @matt I had a similar thought but for some reason calling `self.dataSource.snapshot()` in the section provider causes a segfault (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). I haven't been able to determine why.

Comment: Well you might need some other object that maps between section number and section type. But you really have not shown enough code to advise further.

Comment: Perhaps, but it feels like I'm missing something since one of the principles behind diffable data sources is a single source for UI truth.

Comment: Yes but the idea that that single source is necessarily the diffable data source is a misconception. Mapping from some other object to the table’s diffable data source is a correct strategy too.